# How to use (If its possible) Python WMI to create a dynamic disk on windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, winapi, wmi, device

To provide some background, Diskpart command

```
Convert Dynamic
```

doesn't work on Windows 8.1.
I was trying to see how can I programatically create a dynamic drive through a script. 
I could not find anything on the web.

If anyone has any pointers on how to do such things using WMI, kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation of dynamic disks have been disabled starting from Windows 8